# Comparing two fields and printing result as 1 (if number matches) or 0 (if not) using Python Parser of ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, arcgis-9.3, python-parser

I have two fields named as "sample no" and "data_all" trying to find out whether "sample no" exist on "data_all" or NOT. Using field calculator python 9.3.
if exist print 1 if not print 0 in check_in field. All field are in string format.
For example see attached image in first row "101" found in "data_all" the check_in can print 1 where as in row 2 should be "0". Beginner in python.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**VBScript Parser:**  *(Python Parser example further down)*
In your Field Calculator choose `Show Code Block` and enter the following in the `Pre-Logic Script Code`:

```vbs
d = InStr([data_all], [sampleno])
If d > 0 Then
    e = 1
Else
    e = 0
End If
```

and in the bottom section enter `e`

Syntax is `InStr(<string to search in>, <string to find>)`

**Example** (Sorry I used slightly different field-names in my screenshots):
[image]

**Output:**
[image]

**Note:**
If you have any shorter values such as `1`, `4`, `10` these will be found in longer values like `100`, `204`, `1000`.

**Python Parser:**
In your Field Calculator choose `Show Code Block` and enter the following in the `Pre-Logic Script Code`:

```python
def checknum( sampleno, data_all ):
  e = 0
  for da in data_all.split(";"):
    if str(sampleno) == da:
      e = 1
  return e
```

and in the bottom section enter

```python
checknum( !sampleno!, !data_all! )
```

**Example:**
[image]

**Output:**
[image]

Unlike with the VBScript Parser, the Python Parser example will do an actual match between two values, so shouldn't get any partial matches.

Comment: thanks for immediate reply, managed to get the VBA code running with the error you already highlighted (short values), however unable to get the same result from python code, I am getting "0" for all records?

Comment: Did you get any errors?  Remember that Python is very strict on indenting, so make sure all your indents line up with the same indent level above - e.g. `e=0`, `for...`, `return e` should all be at the same indent, the `if...` one indent further in, and `e=1` another again.  `def...` is not indented, and neither is the `checknum()` in the bottom section.  Also make sure the two parameters match your fieldnames in `checknum( !sampleno!, !data_all! )` and the fieldnames need to be between `!` exclamation marks.

Comment: thanks, no error message coming up, check field get filled with "0" just after the script. It appears that the script is running without any issue but not getting desired result. For indent i have basically copied your code and modified my field name to match the code. assume the code has proper indent? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Let me know if you want me to help debug but @felixip answer below is much more efficient

Answer (score 1):

This is 1 line expression, no block required if data are similar to what shown:

```
(!data.all!find(!sample_no!)>0)*1
```

Comment: Getting syntex error on line 1, no result. Thanks

Comment: `(!data.all!.find(str(!sample_no!))>0)*1`

Comment: thanks, this 1 line expression works but still print "0" for all rows. If I change ">0" to "<0" then print "1" for all rows. Which means it is only executing false not the true. However when I run the expression as "( !data.all! .find('102')>0)*1" then I get "1" as result for first row. Just double checking my ArcGIS is 10.3.0.4284 and python PYTHON 9.3. If this is due to an bug please leave it. I can get around it. Highly appreciate both of you for your great support.

Comment: Your 1st column either numeric or contaiins spaces.  Rtrim Ltrim it

Comment: Thanks, yes you are correct, after doing Ltrim on "sample_no" and checking those values in "data.all" worked very well. Appreciate both of your support.

Comment: Mark as solved please