# Describing input field in ArcMap Field Calculator window?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, terminology

A few days ago I was answering [Comparing two fields and printing result as 1 (if number matches) or 0 (if not) using Python Parser of ArcGIS Field Calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/184199/115)

When describing the process required to get the result using the Codeblock I talked about the "Pre-Logic Script Code", but then didn't know what to call the next box in the window, so I just said

> and in the bottom section enter `e`

What is that *bottom section* actually called, so I can use the right term?

[[image: What do I call the circled field?]]

Comment: Function call box? Guessing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've always referred to the bottom box as the "Expression Box".  In fact if you look at the [**help**](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ARCGISDESKTOP/10.0/HELP/index.html#//00170000004m000000), it is referred to as an "expression".  For example:

> In the tool dialog box, an expression can be entered directly into the
>   Expression parameter, or interactively built using the Field
>   Calculator.

Comment: I just call it the expression too

Answer (score 1):

This is simply called "Expression". And you can refer to it by saying

> Provide definition in Pre-Logic Script Block and then Use checksum( !Numbers!,!data_all! ) as expression